# iOS SwiftUI - NavigationLink open new view and close the current one

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

This is the Login() view:

```
struct Login: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack{
                                    
                Button(action: {
                    
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                }

            }
            
            
            NavigationLink(destination: CreateAccount().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), label: {
                Text("create account")
                
                // and close the current view Login()
            })                
        }       
    }
}
```

Is it possible to open a new view, in this case CreateAccount() and closing the current view Login()?

Comment: What do you mean by close? Is the `Login` open in a sheet?

Comment: "Is the Login open in a sheet" I'm new to iOS development and don't know what you mean. I opened Login() from inside ContentView:                 NavigationLink(destination: Login().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), label: {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "IconColor")!))
                })

Comment: By close I mean if I go to CreateAccount and then back then I don't want to be in Login() again but in ContentView @MrDeveloper

Comment: Got it. A Sheet uses a different modifier, one that appears over the view - it doesn't look like you are using one. The only way to solve this would be to skip NavigationView alltogether or use the `NavigationStack`, which is only available in iOS 16 (beta). Take a look [here](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-observableobject/) to see more, or take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, I would suggest skipping the `NavigationView` altogether, see [here](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-observableobject/) for more info. An example for your situation:

```swift
//You need an `ObservedObject` to do this, and a overall holder view

enum ViewStates{
//Declare possible views
case ContentView
case Login
case CreateAccount

}

//Then use an observableObject

class viewControl: ObservableObject{
@Published var currentView: ViewStates = .ContentView
}

//Finally, pass this into your views. Take a look at the second part of the tutorial I posted below for more info
//such as using `EnvironmentObject` and adding animation. Example implimentation below:


struct ControllerView: View{
@StateObject var controller: viewControl

var body: some View{
switch controller.currentView{
case .ContentView:
ContentView(controller: controller)
case .Login:
Login(controller: controller)
case .CreateAccount:
CreateAccount(controller: controller)
}
}

}
```

Next, you need to have `@ObservedObject var controller: viewControl` in all of your views. Note that you don't need a default statement in the switch clause, because the `enum` declares all possible values. The following is an example CreateAccount view. You also no longer need the dismiss - in fact, that will no longer work.

```swift
struct CreateAccount: View{
@ObservedObject var controller: viewControl

var body: some View{
//Content
Button("Dismiss"){
controller.currentView = .ContentView
}
}

}
```

This will allow you to switch the view by clicking. Instead of a NavigationLink in ContentView, do this:

```swift
Button{
controller.currentView = .CreateAccount
} label: {
Text("Create Account")
}
```

To go back, you just set the value again. This can also be expanded to show more views.

[Second part of the tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-environmentobject/)